# Adding new attribute to existing xml file using sed

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix, sed

I am trying to add attribute under an existing attribute in an XML file. I have been using sed for edit but never used it for update. Would be helpful is someone tell how to add a new attr and an element under that new attrb -

**Current xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<logging_configuration>
 <log_handlers>
  <log_handler name='console-handler' class='oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ConsoleHandler' level='SEVERE' formatter='oracle.core.ojdl.weblogic.ConsoleFormatter'/>

    // add new tag
 </log_handlers>
 </logging_configuration>
```

After updated, need to added new attribute of tag.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<logging_configuration>
 <log_handlers>
  <log_handler name='console-handler' class='oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ConsoleHandler' level='SEVERE' formatter='oracle.core.ojdl.weblogic.ConsoleFormatter'/>

<log_handler name='coherence-console-handler' class='oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ConsoleHandler' level='FINER' formatter='oracle.core.ojdl.weblogic.ConsoleFormatter'/>
 </log_handlers>
 </logging_configuration>
```

Can you help me this, below code try but not added the new tag.

```
log_handler_coherence="<log_handler name='coherence-console-handler' class='oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ConsoleHandler' level='FINER' formatter='oracle.core.ojdl.weblogic.ConsoleFormatter'/>"

C=$(echo $log_handler_coherence | sed 's/\//\\\//g')

sed "/<\/log_handlers>/ s/.*/${C}\n&/" $file
```

But it's not updating.....

Comment: Is `sed` a requirement ? If not, I would do this with an XML capable tool (eg python)

Comment: sed or python also fine....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ log_handler_coherence="<log_handler name='coherence-console-handler' class='oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ConsoleHandler' level='FINER' formatter='oracle.core.ojdl.weblogic.ConsoleFormatter'/>"
$ sed "\~/log_handlers~s~^~$log_handler_coherence\n~" input_file
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<logging_configuration>
 <log_handlers>
  <log_handler name='console-handler' class='oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ConsoleHandler' level='SEVERE' formatter='oracle.core.ojdl.weblogic.ConsoleFormatter'/>

<log_handler name='coherence-console-handler' class='oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ConsoleHandler' level='FINER' formatter='oracle.core.ojdl.weblogic.ConsoleFormatter'/>
 </log_handlers>
 </logging_configuration>
```

Comment: Hi @Hatless, how to get this expectation.... :-  log_handler_ws_async="${domain.home}"   expected output :- ${domain.home}

Comment: Hi @Ban It may be an idea to ask a new question, but, you can try this in the interim `sed 's/[^=]*=//' file` but I do not know the requirements. Please also check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

For python (very basic, rest for you):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse("file.xml")
log_handlers = doc.getElementsByTagName("log_handlers")
newHandler = doc.createElement("log_handler")
newHandler.setAttribute("name","coherence-console-handler");
# more attrs
log_handlers[0].appendChild(newHandler)
print(doc.toprettyxml())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html